# EMMS: browse by folders

Tags: doom, emms, music-player

Is there a way in EMMS that I can browse by folders, instead of artists?

I can use smart browse to open a buffer that can add songs to the playlist. That buffer opens by artists, how can I change it to open by folders instead?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, not without writing some elisp: out of the box, the supported fields to browse by are `artist`, `album`, `genre`, `year` and `performer`.

One could get close to what you want by configuring `dired` to allow adding a track to a playlist.  See [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EMMS#h5o-12) for an idea in this direction.